# Renaming imports when there is no need

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

Reading through the google style guide for python i saw this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

I've also seen similar with say numpy:

```
import numpy as np
```

I understand that it's for name collision resolution, but i've seen it used even when it's the only import/variable with that name.
Why?

Comment: I do this to reduce the number of keystrokes.

Comment: because.... shorter. Same goes for `import pandas as pd` to reduce `pandas.DataFrame(...)` to `pd.DataFrame(...)` - programmers are inheritently lazy folks - thats why we automate.

Comment: It also increases readability by making the less relevant part (the library name) take up less space compared to the more relevant part (the function or class name).

Comment: Three benefits: 1. less typing and better readability, 2. no loss of the specific namespace or risk of collisions like you get with horrible `from xyz import *`, 3. in some specific cases you might benefit from being able to replace one import with another completely compatible import without editing any code except the import line, although I've only benefited from this by changing `import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET` to `import lxml.etree as ET`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just used to give small notations to the big library names so that when you use that library again and again you don't have to use that much lengthy word instead an alias(a reference name) will work